# how may I see if a .iso file is original (to avoid security troubles)?

Tags: operating-systems

I bought a license key for Windows Enterprise on eBay.
The seller sent me a .iso file (Windows Enterprise cannot be downloaded from the Microsoft website directly).
He told me he sent a version of Windows Pro upgradable to Enterprise, so the license I bought may be used to upgrade this version of Windows Pro to enterprise once Windows pro is installed.

This sounds a bit odd to me, I wonder if I should worry about the .iso file he sent and which are the risks involved in installing a non-original operative system (i.e.: might someone take control of my pc?)
I guess it is an older version of Windows he downloaded from the Microsoft site himself (which is no longer available due to commercial reasons) but what if it's an hacked version?

Is there any trick to see if the build of Windows I installed from someone's .iso file is original?

Comment: you want to make a hash of the iso and compare to the published hash of the iso from Microsoft

Comment: I'm trying to install and launch the fciv tool to check the hash but I'm experiencing troubles (it's not recognized as as an internal or external command etc). Is there any other tool to check hashes?

Comment: 7zip, md5sum, etc. There's a lot of software that will let you check hash values.

Answer (score -3):

Is enough to go under Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System and check for last tab: Windows activation.

Here you should see if your windows is activated, the product ID/key and if your Microsoft software is genuine.

LE: My bad, now I see below asking also about trust and checking if any malware. In this case only a md5/hash compare between your .iso and the original one should help

Comment: I put the license key and the Windows Pro system was activated as Enterprise (a message told : "this copy of Windows was activated"), even if I cannot see "activated" on the system info window right now...

Comment: @robertalrp you should see something like:

Windows activation
       Windows is activated
        Product ID: xxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx

Comment: so Windows seems to be activated, let's suppose the .iso is genuine but it contains malware: might the malware survive once I've installed the operative system?

Comment: @robertalrp I know that by the end of XP's life-cycle it was relatively trivial to create install ISOs that would install Windows (and show as activated) plus whatever software you wanted all in one go. I know this is possible in the ISO generation process, in general. I don't know that Windows 10 (or 7 or 8) have any special protections against that. So yes, in general it's possible.

Comment: thank you @Adonalsium  , may I check it by scanning the system from a rescue cd (i.e. Eset rescue disk)?

Comment: @robertalrp There's no guarantee that it would find anything. The usual advice is to reinstall windows, which gets us right back where we started. I'd hunt down a "clean" installer, your license key should work in any installer, and I find the seller's claim that you can't find the install media anywhere anymore to be dubious at best.

Comment: Indeed, this is a problem. The only things I have in mind are:
1. to check the md5 between orig .iso and your .iso (but this is not easy, because you'll need to find the associated .iso with yours and be sure wasn't "touch") or..
2. to use a powerful antivirus you have some trust.
3. to use a program specialized in seeing all the hidden programs (search after procexp on google). In this case, you can see if there is any "special" program and kill it. Indeed, this will not resolve the problem if the malware is built-in inside of another program/executable.